# Custom multiselector in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a custom multiselector that returns an array of all selected values. The multiselector is a parent component that is supposed to do the updating, and it has children components that display the options to be selected.

The presentational components appear to be working, but when I try to pass the multiselector to a form, the submitted array is a record of all presses -- it has duplicate values and deselected values.

I am guessing it has to do with the fact that I don't know where to properly call `prop.onChangeValues` since the SelectionBox containers are working as they should which I assume means that the 'values' array is updating on press as it should.

How should I call prop.onChangeValues properly to ensure it updates correctly? And why is this not working?

**Parent multiselector component**

Calling `props.onChangeValues` as I have below doesn't work. I've also tried adding `props.onChangeValues` as a callback to `setValues` in both setSelections conditions, and also tried `useEffect`, neither worked and useEffect prevented the form's other text input fields from working

```
export function MultiSelector(props) {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  const setSelections = child => {
    if (!values.includes(child.props.value)) {
      setValues([...values, child.props.value]);
    } else {
      setValues(values.filter(value =>
        value !== child.props.value));
    } 
   props.onChangeValues(values) 
};

  return (
    <View>
      <>
      <Text>{props.label}</Text>
      <View>
        {props.children.map(child => (
          <SelectionItem
            onPress ={()=>setSelections(child)}
            style={[
              (values.includes(child.props.value))
                ? Containers.activeSelectionBox
                : Containers.inactiveSelectionBox,
            ]}
            label={child.props.label}
            value={child.props.value}
          />
        ))}
     </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Child components/options to be selected**

```
function Item(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text
          onPress={props.onPress(props.value)}
          style={props.style}>
          {props.label}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have then called the selector in the form like this -:

```
export default class Form extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state =  {
    categories:[],
  }
}

handleCategoriesChange = (newCategory) => {
  this.setState({categories:[...this.state.categories, newCategory]})
}

render(){
 return(
    <View style={Containers.formInputBox}>
       <RadioSelector label="Choose categories" 
onChangeValues={this.handleCategoriesChange}>  
         <Item label="label 1" value="value 1"/>
           <Item label="label 2" value="value 2"/>
           <Item label="label 3" value="value 3"/>
           <Item label="label 4" value="value 4"/>
       </RadioSelector>
    </View>
  )}
}
```